# UISwitch with custom images on tintColor and onTintColor properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiswitch

I am trying to set custom images on UISwitch (in iOS7) by setting its tintColor and onTintColor properties, like in the code below.

```
    UIImage* onImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial-switch-on.png"];
    onImage = [onImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

    UIImage* offImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial-switch-off.png"];
    offImage = [offImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];


    [self.mySwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:onImage]];
    [self.mySwitch setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:offImage]];
```

I don't know why my images aren't stretch. With or without

```
  "resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch"
```

I obtain the same result, a tiled image. I can't figure out why resizableImageWithCapInsets: method doesn't work.  How can I stretch my images? Or make them fit into UISwitch.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I tried setting the onTint and ThumbTint color with imagePattern without any luck of getting it correctly.

Comment: Somehow, I set tintColor to clearColor and behind the switch, in same point, I placed an UIImageView with the image that I wanted for offImage.